# Chrome's development console say there is an error on an incorrect line number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I've been experiencing an issue with Chrome's development console. The console says that there's a JavaScript error, and it tells me the number. But the problem is, many times, the line number it is referring to does not relate at all to the error in my code.

For example, currently, I have an error which says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined`, which is understandable. However, when the console tries to tell me the line number that the error occurred on, that line never called a variable `Title` in the first place. Why is it referencing that line number? See image below:

[image: Image of Chrome's development console error that references a line number that has nothing to do with the line number]

In the image above, line #83 in my code has nothing to do with `Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined.` So I don't know where the error ocured since many times in my code, I call a field called `Title`.

**Edit:** I tried this also on Internet Explorer 10 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChMpv.png)), and it gave me the correct line number. Perhaps this is a glitch on Google's side.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that chromes interpreter is not taking you to an exact line but instead a segment of code causing the issue, some debuggers (maybe chrome included) are not always 100% accurate and may refer you to a block or segment of the code causing the problems. In this case it looks like the issue is with `lastCharacter = allObjs[allObjs.length -1].Title]...` which is in that same segment..

If an error occurs and its not exact with the line number I would recommend setting some breakpoints on that segment and seeing what the result is or console logging `.Title` where its used in that block of code.

Comment: I think you're right, that it is Chrome's interpreter. Because I tried this on Internet Explorer too and it gave me an accurate number (see my edit in my original post).

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating from Firefox.  I've noticed that it's more accurate when identifying the line number in the source than Chrome.  Chrome has repeatedly been off by 9+ lines on occasion.  It's very frustrating.